# Connect to more than one Arduino with Adobe AIR

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using the arduinconnector ANE to connect to an arduino baord in an AIR application. https://code.google.com/p/as3-arduino-connector/

Can anyone tell me if its possible to connect to more than 1 board, simply by instantiating additional instances of the ANE and passing in unique port #'s?

Or is there some reason why this isn't possible and a unique AIR application is required for every arduino you connect to?

Comment: don't know if this is a definitive answer, or only pertains to this ANE, but was told by the dev that The flash runtime is all shared memory space, so you will run into conflicts. Needs to be reengineered.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be possible with `as3Glue` as per the [docs](https://code.google.com/p/as3glue/):

> as3Glue is an ActionScript 3 library that enables communication between Flash/Flex/AIR applications and Arduino boards. **It can together with one or several Arduino boards** be used to monitor sensors (such as rotary encoders and motion detectors), control actuators (such as LEDs and motors) and interface other electronics (such as RFID readers) from Flash, Flex and AIR applications.

`as3Glue` can be used with `as3-arduino-connector` as mentioned in the [docs](https://code.google.com/p/as3-arduino-connector/):

> Using with as3Glue
>
> Download either the SWC or Source Code from the Downloads section of this project for a patched version of as3Glue. This patched version has the exact same interfaces as v20, with a notable exception of the constructor. When you instantiate a new "Arduino" object, replace the IP address and port with the COM port and baud rate. For example :
>
> public var myArduino:Arduino = new Arduino("COM10", 57600);